# Issue with running a simple HTTP server from Docker locally

Tags: docker, julia

I am trying to run a simple Julia HTTP server from Docker.

```
FROM julia:latest

COPY server.jl server.jl

ENV PORT=8080

RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("HTTP");'

CMD [ "julia", "server.jl"]
```

I kick off Docker via this bash command

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 test-julia
```

and then I just send requests to `127.0.0.1:8080` via curl which yields

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However, if I just run the server using my local Julia without using the docker via `julia --project=. server.jl` then it runs fine and returns `Hello` as expected.

What's the setting I need to do with Docker to make it work?

The content of `server.jl` is simple and simply returns "hello" as below

```
using HTTP

ENV["PORT"] = "8080"

const PORT = parse(Int, ENV["PORT"])

print("Listening on port $PORT")

# HTTP.listen! and HTTP.serve! are the non-blocking versions of HTTP.listen/HTTP.serve
server = HTTP.serve(PORT) do request::HTTP.Request
    print("got a request")
   @show request
   @show request.method
   @show HTTP.header(request, "Content-Type")
   @show request.body
   try
       return HTTP.Response("Hello")
   catch e
       return HTTP.Response(400, "Error: $e")
   end
end

#close(server)
```

Answer (score 2):

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/http-jl-in-docker/20764/3

Just use `0.0.0.0` to listen all address cos by default the HTTP.jl package uses `Socket.localhost` as the URL which is `127.0.0.1` which only works for requests from within docker not from outside.

`server = HTTP.serve("0.0.0.0", PORT) do request::HTTP.Request`

does the trick